# Запрос для вывода названия таблиц по одной из MS SQL по порядку

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Вопрос в следующем у меня есть название базы данных MS SQL  к примеру MyDb.
Мне нужно по порядку получить названия таблиц(иммено один запрос->имя одной таблицы). Для MySQL я бы прошелся вот так

```
SELECT table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema='MyDb' limit 0,1
```

Т.e. я бы менял LIMIT до количества таблиц в базе. В  MS SQL Limita нет.
Далее я сделал запрос для извлечения одной таблицы в MS SQL

```
SELECT TOP 1 name  FROM MyDb.sys.Tables
```

Запрос работает все в порядке вытаскивает одну таблицу. Собственно как мне пройтись этим запросом по названиям всех таблиц в этой базе данных по порядку(это очень важно, не нужно предлагать использовать SELECT *). Уважаемые знатоки MS SQL помогите модифицировать мой запрос так, как если бы мне нужно было пройтись по MySql c LIMITом. Если вопрос где то уже обсуждался скиньте ссылку, я к сожалению не нашел.

Собственно решил подправить для ясности
Вот как я думаю решить данный вопрос, допустим количество таблиц numtable, я пытаюсь сделать вот так

```
SELECT TOP 1 name  FROM MyDb.sys.Tables WHERE name not in (SELECT TOP (numtables-1) name FROM MyDb.sys.Tables)
```

Но запрос не отрабатывает.

Comment: и что вы думаете, если нет `LIMIT` то вообще нет никакой альтернативной инструкции? или пронумеровать строки и выбирать по номеру

Comment: Я не говорю что нет никакой альтернативы, я прошу помощи с этой альтернативой как раз. Как мне альтернативно пройтись по именам таблиц в базе данных MS SQL, как на примере я прошелся бы для MySQL. Запрос для получения одной таблицы у меня есть и есть общее количество таблиц, больше ничего нет.

Comment: Альтернатива: Offset и fetch: http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_paging/page4.html

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо пользователю @msi дал совет собственно вот что получилось, может кому пригодиться

```
SELECT  name  FROM MyDb.sys.Tables ORDER BY name OFFSET 3 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY;
```